# Backup Excel personal.xlsb to OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365, onedrive

I am using **OneDrive for Business** and I want to backup my **Excel personal macro file**; `personal.xlsb`.

I have tried the following methods without success.

1. Add folder to OneDrive - I cannot seem to locate this option.
2. Move `personal.xlsb` to My Documents and change the option `File -> Options -> Advanced -> General -> At Startup open all files in`. Excel opens the file but does not allow changes to be made to the file.
3. Move `personal.xlsb` to My Documents and change the option `File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Trusted Locations ->` 
   change `Excel default location: User StartUp`. Excel does not even open the file.

Any suggestions on how to automatically sync this file to OneDrive?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't change Personal.xlsb Location. it's by design.

Comment: @HerbGu, it appears to be that way, unfortunately. Now I need to identify how to back this up via an alternative method. I can think of the following options **1.** have a script that copies this file (and others) to OneDrive **2.** make OneDrive look at the files that I want to backup (although I do not think that this is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is possible by using the `mklink` statement.

```
mklink /j "C:\Users\{UserName}\OneDrive\Backup\XLSTART\" "C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\"
```

Problem is that Excel puts a lock on `personal.xlsb` and will not sync it until Excel is closed. So far that is acceptable for me.

Some links for reference.

- [The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows - How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)
- [Synchronizing any folder on your system with OneDrive - Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/developingfordynamicsgp/2014/09/11/synchronizing-any-folder-on-your-system-with-onedrive/)
- [Sync any folder in Windows to OneDrive](https://evotec.xyz/sync-folder-windows-to-onedrive/)
- [How to Sync Any Folder to OneDrive in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/92892-sync-any-folder-onedrive-windows-10-a.html)